# hInstance in CreateWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

I use `CreateWindow` to create the main window. `hInstance` in `WNDCLASSEX` specifies the instance under which the class is registered. So I need `hInstance` in `CreateWindow` function to find it.

I use `CreateWindow` to create a button. No user-defined `WNDCLASSEX` now. The BUTTON's `WNDCLASSEX` is global. But I still need to pass an `hInstance` to the function? Why and what is the right value to pass?

In Microsoft's example it's `(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hMainWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)`, but I have no idea of what it is.

Please also tell me if I had anything wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The only two `HINSTANCE` values I see are `nullptr` (or `NULL`) and `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` (or whatever was passed to `WinMain`). Honestly, I've never seen a difference that I can recall between the two for use in class registration or window creation, so I always use the latter and it always works fine.

Comment: @chris: `GetModuleHandle` will return an `HMODULE` not an `HINSTANCE`, are they the same?

Comment: Yes, there was a difference in 16-bit Windows, but they are identical now. See: [Raymond Chen's Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx)

Comment: @chris: but there may be more than one `HINSTANCE` for one `HMODULE`. so what if I registered different `WNDCLASS` with the same NAME during runtime under different instances? That's quite possible, I think.

Comment: Since the programs now run in separate address spaces, both represent the base address of the module. AFAIK, `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` will return different physical addresses for the same executable being run twice in succession.

Comment: may be this will help you http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/how-to-create-a-basic-window-in-c/#comment-10815

Comment: @chris: so actually you mean there is no more `HMODULE`, only `HINSTANCE`?

Comment: @nabroyan, *So, whenever the user attempts to interact with ANY program window inside that Windows Government, the Windows O/S INTERCEPTS that communication FIRST.* Priceless.

Comment: @Immueggpain, Sure, but stealing from the article: *When it came to design Win32, the question then arose, "What do we do with HINSTANCE and HMODULE for Win32?" Since programs ran in separate address spaces, you didn't have instance handles visible across process boundaries. So the designers took the only thing they had: The base address of the module. This was analogous to the HMODULE, since the file header describes the contents of the file and its structure. And it was also analogous to the HINSTANCE, since the data was kept in the data segment, which was mapped into the process directly.*

Comment: @chris, Got it. It seems to me that HINSTANCE makes more sense than HMODULE since it's runtime. Then can you tell me what's the right value to pass when creating a control? You know it already has a hWndParent. So many examples I saw just use NULL and it works fine.

Comment: Both `NULL` and `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` have always worked fine for me, and different tutorials choose both of those options overall, so I'm not sure which is technically better. I'm tempted to say they both do the same thing internally in this case.

Comment: @chris, That's fine. Can you post an answer so that I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I still need to pass an hInstance to the function? Why and what is the right value to pass?

As for the why, it would be a bit pointless (at least from a winapi perspective) to make a whole new function that takes everything but that and just uses the parent's or something when all other parameters still have a use.

I personally don't know for sure what the right value to pass in is, but I use `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)`, which should be equivalent to the instance passed into `WinMain`. It would also be the same as the one Microsoft's example uses (which gets the instance used to create the parent window) if that's what you use to create the parent window. The difference would come in if using a different application's window as the parent. The other main option I see used is `nullptr`/`NULL`, which has worked the same way as the aforementioned options every time I have used it.

If there's a subtle difference today between using `NULL` and the application's `HINSTANCE`, I'd like to know, but either of those should work fine for creating child controls on your windows.

Answer (score 5):

I found in MSDN dated from 2001 for `CreateWindow` and `CreateWindowEx`

`hInstance`

**Windows 95/98/Me:** [in] Handle to the instance of the module to be associated with the window.

**Windows NT/2000/XP:** This value is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a window, you specify the class of which an instance is created with a string (`lpClassName`) in the first parameter of `CreateWindow`.

`hInstance` is used for identification in case more than one DLL referenced contains a class with the same name.

For more information see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873